# append child component route to the parent component route

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. the child component route looks like 
`/practice/NATA/(test:edit/59afb586c99fbb3068fce1f6/courses)`
and in the same child component clicking a button should change the route to `/practice/NATA/(test:edit/59afb586c99fbb3068fce1f6/courses/duplicate/<courseid>)` 
but i am getting the route like this `/practice/NATA/(test:edit/59afb586c99fbb3068fce1f6/(courses//test:duplicate/593107b273790c30c4e08b03))`

the child component routing module looks like this

```
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: '', component: NewEditPracticeComponent, outlet: 'test', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
    { path: 'duplicate/:courseid', component: NewEditPracticeComponent, outlet: 'test', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
]),
```

and `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { test: ['duplicate', item._id ]}}]"`

the parent component routing module looks like this

```
 [RouterModule.forChild([
{
  path: ':course', component: PracticeComponent, canActivate: [CourseGuard], children: [
    { path: '', component: PracticeListComponent, outlet: 'test', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'new', loadChildren: './new-edit-practice/new-edit-practice.module#EditPracticeModule', outlet: 'test', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
    { path: 'edit/:testid', loadChildren: './new-edit-practice/new-edit-practice.module#EditPracticeModule', outlet: 'test', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
    // { path: 'duplicate/:courseid/:testid', loadChildren: './new-edit-practice/new-edit-practice.module#EditPracticeModule', outlet: 'test', canActivate: [AdminGuard] },

  ]
},
{ path: '', loadChildren: './practice-test/practice-test.module#PracticeTestModule' }
 ])]
```

and it is rendering the path `edit/:testid`. thanks in advance.

Comment: your child component path will always add after parent component path.

Comment: @piyushjain it's not possible to modify like that ?

Comment: can you please provide a stackblitz url ?

Comment: @piyushjain I cant it contains a lot of dependency code. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append "./" to your routerlink attribute like this
 `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { test: ['./duplicate', item._id ]}}]"`. It will ensure that the router will look inside the current router.
You can check more info [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)